# Can't empty $scope.labels and $scope.data used when drawing angular-charts

Tags: angularjs, angular-chart

I am using angular-chart.js to draw some graphs. And I am using array values to set the values for `$scope.labels` and `$scope.data` from database. I want to make the `$scope.labels` and `$scope.data` empty after each call of the function. please find the below code

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"])
.controller("LineCtrl", function ($scope) {
     $scope.labels = [];      
      $scope.data = [[]];
   $scope.graphFunc = function(array) {


      for(var i =0; i < array.length; i++)
      {
        $scope.labels.push(array[i].name);
        $scope.data[0].push(array[i].age)  
      }

      $scope.onClick = function (points, evt) {
        console.log(points, evt);
      };
```

```
      $scope.datasetOverride = [{ yAxisID: 'y-axis-1' }, { yAxisID: 'y-axis-2' }];
      $scope.options = {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [
            {
              id: 'y-axis-1',
              type: 'linear',
              display: true,
              position: 'left'
            },
            {
              id: 'y-axis-2',
              type: 'linear',
              display: true,
              position: 'right'
            }
          ]
        }
      };

   };

   $scope.labels = [];
   $scope.data = [[]];
});
```

But then the graph is not appearing. Please note that my array is a dynamic and array format is as follows

```
var arrayVal = [{name:A,age:10},{name:B,age:30}];
```

**UPDATED**
HTML

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data"
chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options"
chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride" chart-click="onClick">
</canvas>
```

Comment: can u also share html part of it, how the directive is being used?

Comment: Maybe create a minimal reproducible example

Comment: What invokes the `$scope.graphFunc` function? Where does it get its `array` parameter?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to clear them out?  Since/If they are the backing variables to the chart, if you clear them out, the chart will be cleared out and therefore give you the blank graph that you're seeing.

Comment: @kendavidson my array will be having different values at different times when the graphFunc is invoked by the user. Currently what happens is the new array values are appending to the previous array so that generated graph is having same value more than once. I want to get rid of that

Comment: @georgeawg graphFunc is invoked by a ng-change in a dropdown. and when the dropdown values are selected the array gets its values from database and the graph will be drawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the issue which is rather than declaring $scope.labels and $scope.data inside controller, by declaring these two global variables inside chartFunc() this issue can be overcome. Therefore you don't have to reinitialize the two variables at the end of the chartFunc().

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"])
.controller("LineCtrl", function ($scope) {

   $scope.graphFunc = function(array) {

        $scope.labels = [];      
      $scope.data = [[]];
      for(var i =0; i < array.length; i++)
      {
        $scope.labels.push(array[i].name);
        $scope.data[0].push(array[i].age)  
      }

      $scope.onClick = function (points, evt) {
        console.log(points, evt);
      };
      $scope.datasetOverride = [{ yAxisID: 'y-axis-1' }, { yAxisID: 'y-axis-2' }];
      $scope.options = {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [
            {
              id: 'y-axis-1',
              type: 'linear',
              display: true,
              position: 'left'
            },
            {
              id: 'y-axis-2',
              type: 'linear',
              display: true,
              position: 'right'
            }
          ]
        }
      };

   };
});
```

What happens is each time the user wants to see a graph the two variables are reinitialized inside the chartFunc and previous array values are removed autuomatically